# how to make run php and web.py

Tags: php, web.py

[Same question is asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444445/how-to-run-php-and-web-py-together/5482441#5482441)
but i didn't understand the answers for same like mod_php and mod_wsgi. I've a code.py through which I want to call php file in render submit, which i'm unable to do. Same php file when I run without code.py it works fine, even echo is not working and I don't know the reason for the same.

Code of code.py

```
import web
import os
import datetime
import inspect
import sys


urls = ('/', 'upload')
app = web.application(urls, globals())
web.config.debug = True

class upload:
    def __init__(self):
        self.render = web.template.render('templates/')        
    def GET(self):
        return self.render.webht()
    def POST(self):
        return self.render.first()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run()
```

Code of webht.html(in GET)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form class="" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return no_file_check()" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="form_id" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <button id="input_" type="submit" class="submit_button">
          Button            </button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Code for first.php(In POST method of code.py)

```
<?php echo "hello there"; ?>
```

Kindly help me with this problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details about why you're unable to do it, and what specifically what you don't understand about the answers to the other question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've tried to edit my question, to clear my doubt.

Comment: You've probably noticed numerous people saying, "this doesn't make sense", which is why a solution is tough to find. Provide a really basic example (i.e., the code)... It sounds like web.py is handling the request and then rendering a response. You'll trying(?) to have webpy render a PHP file, but you then need to feed that rendered result back through PHP to be converted to HTML prior to sending to the browser. I suppose you can write an unloadhook in webpy to take response contents and pipe that through PHP, but why bother?

Comment: @Peter I'm inserting a code.py and get & post files it would be helpful if you can help.

Comment: Your python looks fine. However, when the POST() is executed, your python `web.py` renderer will look for the file whose name starts `first.`. It's confusing, because convention says to name the file `first.html`, but web.py doesn't care, it will walk the directory and pick any file starting `first.`, including `first.blahblah`. In your example it will indeed find `first.php`, and will use the web.py renderer to generate HTML, but _it_does_not_recognize_the_file_as_php_. So you'll get the text contents of first.php. Sorry: that's why you don't see python & php mixing.

Comment: @Peter but I would like to run a php file. So how should I do that.

Comment: You'll have to teach python to understand PHP, my friend. Or, solve your exercise with the proper tool: All python or all php. I really don't understand why there is any benefit to running the hybrid. Both systems have rich libraries.

Comment: Then I'll try to do it in other way i guess. Thanks for letting me know.